# Attribute Error though attribute is assigned

Tags: python, django

```
from channels.generic.websockets import WebsocketDemultiplexer,WebsocketConsumer
from .models import TwilioCallBinding
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums,types
import json
import base64
from .SpeechClientBridge import SpeechClientBridge


class MediaStreamConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
                                   encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MULAW,
                                   sample_rate_hertz=8000,
                                   language_code='en-US'
                                 )

    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config,interim_results=True)

    def on_transcription_response(response):
        if not response.results:
            return

        result = response.results[0]
        if not result.alternatives:
            return

        transcription = result.alternatives[0].transcript
        print("Transcription: " + transcription)

    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        self.message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
        self.bridge = SpeechClientBridge(MediaStreamConsumer.streaming_config,
                                         MediaStreamConsumer.on_transcription_response)

    
        print("****************************************")

    def raw_receive(self, message, **kwargs):
        data = json.loads(message['text'])

        if data["event"] in ("connected", "start"):
            print(f"Media WS: Received event '{data['event']}': {message}")
        
        if data["event"] == "media":
            media = data["media"]
            chunk = base64.b64decode(media["payload"])

            self.bridge.add_request(chunk)

        if data["event"] == "stop":
            print(f"Media WS: Received event 'stop': {message}")
            print("Stopping...")

    def disconnect(self, message, **kwargs):
        self.bridge.terminate()
```

I am getting same error on message receive as well as disconnect event

```
AttributeError: 'MediaStreamConsumer' object has no attribute 'bridge'
```

I have assigned bridge attribute in connect event

```
def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
    self.message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    self.bridge = SpeechClientBridge(MediaStreamConsumer.streaming_config,
                                         MediaStreamConsumer.on_transcription_response)
```

then why i am getting `AttributeError` ?

Edit:
I have added `print("*****************************")` to check whether `connect` method is automatically called or not.

Trace after making changes.

```
[2020/10/28 21:27:43] HTTP POST /call-application/media-stream/ 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:38000]
[2020/10/28 21:27:44] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /websockets/livecallstream/ [127.0.0.1:38002]
****************************************
[2020/10/28 21:27:44] WebSocket CONNECT /websockets/livecallstream/ [127.0.0.1:38002]
Media WS: Received event 'connected': <channels.message.Message object at 0x7f579c0506a0>
Media WS: Received event 'start': <channels.message.Message object at 0x7f579c067518>
2020-10-28 21:27:44,714 - ERROR - worker - Error processing message with consumer datasleek_twilio.consumers.MediaStreamConsumer:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 119, in run
    consumer(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/base.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.dispatch(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/base.py", line 70, in dispatch
    return self.get_handler(message, **kwargs)(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/datasleek/tracker/datasleek_twilio/consumers.py", line 62, in raw_receive
    self.bridge.add_request(chunk)
AttributeError: 'MediaStreamConsumer' object has no attribute 'bridge'
2020-10-28 21:27:44,735 - ERROR - worker - Error processing message with consumer datasleek_twilio.consumers.MediaStreamConsumer:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 119, in run
    consumer(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/base.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.dispatch(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/base.py", line 70, in dispatch
    return self.get_handler(message, **kwargs)(message, **kwargs)
  File "/home/datasleek/tracker/datasleek_twilio/consumers.py", line 62, in raw_receive
    self.bridge.add_request(chunk)
AttributeError: 'MediaStreamConsumer' object has no attribute 'bridge'
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have edited the question details to cross-verify your question. Can you please check and guide me. Thanks!

Comment: that print() statement is pretty redundant since when the server is started it will automatically stream through all the relevant files. Indent your print() statement within the connect method and you will be able to see that it will indeed not print. As the user mentioned, make sure the connect() method is called and only subsequently a call is made to access the attribute of it

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 it was my mistake print statement was inside the connect() method in original code. I did mistake while editing question. However you are correct, ```connect``` is not called automatically. I made some changes in the code and it solved my problem. Thanks !

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks you were correct ```connect``` method is not called automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Carcigenicate and @AzyCrw4282 in the comments `connect` is not called automatically. Though i am still unsure how websockets connect if `connect` is not called automatically because i could see messages coming. Anyways i have made the following changes and **after making these changes i was able to see transcription in console.**

```
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
                                   encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MULAW,
                                   sample_rate_hertz=8000,
                                   language_code='en-US'
                                 )

streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config,interim_results=True)


def on_transcription_response(response):
    if not response.results:
        return

    result = response.results[0]
    if not result.alternatives:
        return

    transcription = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    print("Transcription: " + transcription)


bridge = None

def set_bridge():
    global bridge

    if bridge is None:
        bridge = SpeechClientBridge(streaming_config,on_transcription_response)


class MediaStreamConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        self.message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})


    def raw_receive(self, message, **kwargs):
        set_bridge()

        data = json.loads(message['text'])

        if data["event"] in ("connected", "start"):
            print(f"Media WS: Received event '{data['event']}': {message}")
        
        if data["event"] == "media":
            media = data["media"]
            chunk = base64.b64decode(media["payload"])

            bridge.add_request(chunk)
   
        if data["event"] == "stop":
            print(f"Media WS: Received event 'stop': {message}")
            print("Stopping...")


    def disconnect(self, message, **kwargs):
        bridge.terminate()
```